# EF Core scaffolding and this error have but database I think not problem how I fixed it

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Error:

> The types of the properties specified for the foreign key {'CityId'} on entity type 'JobAdvert' do not match the types of the properties in the principal key {'Id'} on entity type 'City'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z74xJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/maZuh.png

```
-- Table: public.cities

-- DROP TABLE public.cities;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.cities
(
    id smallint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cities_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


-- Table: public.cities

-- DROP TABLE public.cities;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.cities
(
    id smallint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cities_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.cities
    OWNER to postgres;



     Table: public.job_adverts

-- DROP TABLE public.job_adverts;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_adverts
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    employer_id integer NOT NULL,
    job_position_id integer NOT NULL,
    city_id integer NOT NULL,
    description character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    min_salary integer,
    max_salary integer,
    number_of_open_positions integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    application_deadline timestamp with time zone,
    is_active boolean NOT NULL,
    is_deleted boolean NOT NULL,
    working_type_id smallint,
    working_time_id smallint,
    CONSTRAINT job_adverts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT job_adverts_city_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (city_id)
        REFERENCES public.cities (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT job_adverts_employer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (employer_id)
        REFERENCES public.employers (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT job_adverts_job_position_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (job_position_id)
        REFERENCES public.job_positions (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT job_adverts_working_time_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (working_time_id)
        REFERENCES public.working_times (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT job_adverts_working_type_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (working_type_id)
        REFERENCES public.working_types (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID
)
```

Comment: The message is telling you that the `city_id` column of the `job_adverts` table doesn't have the same type as the `id` column of the `cities` table.  If you look at your `CREATE TABLE` statements, you can see that that is indeed the case: one has type `smallint` and the other has type `integer`.

Comment: I assume you'll fix the schema so you don't need a .net workaround?

Comment: @jeremyLakeman of course :)